# Position a <div> element always on the right, also when viewer zooms out in browser

Tags: css, html, web

This screenshot shows my problem:

http://oi45.tinypic.com/2vskt2a.jpg">

My page looks as expected (top image), but once a viewer zooms out, the element on the right moves inwards, leaving an empty space on the right (bottom image). This should not happen; the element should always remain on the right.

This is the CSS code I tried; it worked well until I tested with the browser's zooom out function.

```
#left {
    width:920px;
    top:120px;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
}
#right {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    left:920px;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: don't use fixed `width` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

HTML:

```
<div id="head">
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
    <p>
        content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
    </p>
</div>
<div id="foot">
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#head{
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
}

#foot{
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
}

#content{
    height:100px;
}

#nav{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    float:right;
}
```

[**DEMO**​](http://jsfiddle.net/wsKfd/1/)

***UPD***: updated html, so it works properly with some content inside.

***UPD2***: since I touched content, you may add `overflow:auto` for your content as well, so it will be still viewable if it doesn't fully fit: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wsKfd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do it in percentages  (assuming your screen resolution is 1024 px)

```
#left {
width:90%;
float:left;
height:400px;
background:#fff;}

#right {
float:right;
width:10%;
height:400px;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```